# Dojo: is it bad to have 'require' in the loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, dojo

Imagine that we have three widgets: Foo, Bar and Baz. Now we have an array with length of 10 with 'Foo', 'Bar' and 'Baz' words. We would like to instantiate corresponding Widget depending on the string-element in the array:

```
array.forEach(arrayOfStrings, function(arrayElement) {
  require(['some_path/' + arrayElement], function(cls) {
    new cls();
});
```

Is it a bad practise to use `require` in `forEach()` loop? Are there any good ways to improve this code (may be store already used elements)?

Comment: It's quite odd (dynamic module loading in a loop), but not necessarily bad practise, `require` will do caching on its own.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bergi suggested a require in loop is not necessarily a bad practice, `require` also cache your AMD modules.

Alternatives:

01) You can use a more declarative approach, example use a loop in order to create HTML markups and attach the result to the DOM, example:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" data-dojo-type="app/foo" />
```

and use `dojo/parser` in order to `Auto Require` module `foo` [more info on auto require here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html).

02) Use a simple [factory](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-factory/). You can *get rid* of the `require` in your loop and delegate its usage in the factory. Some pseudo code:

```
array.forEach(arrayOfStrings, function(arrayElement) {
  UserFactory.createFoo(); // use the factory instead
});
//... factory object here
UserFactory.createFoo = function() {
    require(['some_path/foo'], function(cls) {
       new cls();
    });
};
```

A more "dynamic" version (just some pseudo code)

```
array.forEach(arrayOfStrings, function(type) {
  UserFactory.createWidget(type); // use the factory instead
});
//... factory object here
UserFactory.createWidget= function(type) {
    require(['some_path/' + type], function(cls) {
       new cls();
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm, does creating a factory solve the issue? You would need to extend that factory with `createBar` and `createBaz`. And then you would have to write a large `if(foo) { ... } else if (bar) { ... }` statement to make sure the right factory is being called.

Or if you have separate factories, then you still have to build an array of the factories.

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks for sharing, I suggested the factory in order to delegate object initialization outside "require in the loop" as h3d0 was not sure if it was the right approach. Regarding your point about large if statement is possible to create a more dynamic require path as in the example I have edited. Off-course is a very simplistic example in my answer. Thanks for your comment.